# mvn compilation warning (unused import) due to javadoc imports

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, javadoc, compiler-warnings

I have been working on java project that is using maven for building. We also use eclipse for development for all the goodies (auto-complete etc.) One thing that I have noticed is that the imports in classes due to javadoc comments, where eclipse is fine and does not raise a warning, when I build the same source code with maven I get a warning about unused imports.
e.g. if I have the following javadoc

```
/**
 * blah blah {@link SomeClass}
 */
```

and SomeClass is not required in the actual source, it is imported automatically by eclipse and no warning is raised, but when i build it with maven I get the unused import warning.
For maven I ma using the eclipse compiler as

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
        <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <optimize>true</optimize> 
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will do the trick:

```
/**
 * blah blah {@link full.package.name.SomeClass}
 */
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, and the clutter that will produce.